# Database design for subscription billing

Tags: database-design, recurring-billing

Looking for some guidance on the basic design of the database for a recurring billing system.

The design I've come up with has one table to store the next cycle of the subscription (either on the same or new plan, same or different price, or not renewing), and another to store the the applied subscription (what products were bought when, at what price). This is what I've got:

```
Subscriptions
+----+------------+--------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
| ID | customerID | itemID | nextBillingDate | nextBillingPrice | notRenewingReason |
+----+------------+--------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
|  1 |         10 |      2 | NULL            |              280 | Too expensive     |
|  2 |         10 |      3 | NULL            |              120 | Too expensive     |
|  3 |         11 |      2 | 2015-06-18      |              290 |                   |
|  4 |         10 |      2 | 2016-10-14      |              290 |                   |
+----+------------+--------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+


SubscriptionHistory

+----+--------+------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| ID | subsID | startDate  |  endDate   | price | extInvoiceID | paid  |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
|  1 |      1 | 2012-09-04 | 2013-09-03 |   280 | 81654        | TRUE  |
|  2 |      2 | 2013-03-01 | 2013-03-31 |     0 | NULL         | TRUE  |
|  3 |      2 | 2013-04-01 | 2013-09-03 |   120 | 81812        | TRUE  |
|  4 |      1 | 2013-09-04 | 2014-09-03 |   280 | 84221        | TRUE  |
|  5 |      2 | 2013-09-04 | 2014-09-03 |   120 | 84221        | TRUE  |
|  6 |      3 | 2014-06-18 | 2015-06-17 |   290 | 85312        | TRUE  |
|  7 |      4 | 2015-10-14 | 2016-10-13 |   290 | 87421        | FALSE |
+----+--------+------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
```

It has to support the following use cases:

1. Subscriptions are for a year or 3 years
2. A customer subscribes to a product plan
3. A customer can subscribe to multiple products
4. Add-ons for the product can be included in the    subscription
5. An add-on can be added part way through a subscription
6. An add-on can be added as a trial for a period of time  during a subscription
7. Some subscriptions may be a reduced rate (e.g. agreed a second subscription for free due to a special circumstance)
8. At renewal the plan, add-ons and price may change
9. Ability to record a reason for not renewing
10. Full history should be visible for any customer, for example in the above database you can see customer 10:

    - Joined 2012-09-04
    - Added an add-on to subscription on 2013-04-01 after one month trial
    - Didn't renew as too expensive, so expired on 2014-09-03
    - Subscribed again on 2015-10-14 at a higher price, with payment outstanding

Any pointers?

Comment: You may get some help if you show what you have done so far. People on here wont do it for you.

Comment: @w0051977 I've added what I've got so far

Comment: @marcus What is the status of your solution? Maybe you have found some open source solution? Looking into this question 4years later, interesting to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This is a table containing your addons. You didn't explicitly say your addons cost money but you allude to that so I've included a price. I've also assumed that addons are tied to particular products. If your addons change over time I'd have a `beg_date` and `end_date` in this table just like in the `product` table.

```
addon
    id              unsigned int(P)
    product_id      unsigned int(F product_id)
    description     varchar(255)
    price           double

+----+------------+-----------------+-------+
| id | product_id | description     | price |
+----+------------+-----------------+-------+
|  1 |          1 | This is addon 1 | 11.25 |
|  2 |          1 | This is addon 2 | 22.50 |
|  3 |          1 | This is addon 3 | 15.00 |
| .. | .......... | ............... | ..... |
+----+------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Just a regular old `customer` table...

```
customer
    id              unsigned int(P)
    salutation      varchar(4)
    first_name      varchar(50)
    ...

+----+------------+------------+-----+
| id | salutation | first_name | ... |
+----+------------+------------+-----+
|  1 |        Mr. |       John | ... |
|  2 |       Mrs. |       Jane | ... |
| .. | .......... | .......... | ... |
+----+------------+------------+-----+
```

Here's all the `addon`'s every customer has ever purchased or trialed. In this example `end_date` defaults to `NULL` and won't have a value in it until the customer stops using the addon. Alternately you could fill in the `end_date` based on when the associated `product` is set to expire. Notice the customer paid full price for addon 1, nothing for addon 2 (because they just trialed it) and they got addon 3 at a discounted rate.

```
customer_addon
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    customer_id             unsigned int(F customer.id)
    addon_id                unsigned int(F addon.id)
    beg_date                date
    end_date                date // default NULL
    price                   double
    renewed                 enum('f','t')
    decline_reason_id       unsigned int(F decline_reason.id)

+----+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
| id | customer_id | addon_id | beg_date   | end_date   | price | renewed | decline_reason_id |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
|  1 |           1 |        1 | 2015-01-10 | 2016-01-10 | 11.25 |       f |                 1 |
|  2 |           1 |        2 | 2015-01-10 | 2015-02-10 |  0.00 |       f |                 2 |
|  3 |           1 |        3 | 2015-10-25 |       NULL | 10.00 |    NULL |              NULL |
| .. | ........... | ........ | .......... | .......... | ..... | ....... | ................. |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
```

Here's all the `product`'s every customer has ever purchased. In this example I'm populating `end_date` with the calculated date the subscription should expire. You can see the customer paid full price for Product 2 but got a discount for Product 3.

```
customer_product
    id                      unsigned int(P)
    customer_id             unsigned int(F customer.id)
    product_id              unsigned int(F product.id)
    beg_date                date
    end_date                date
    price                   double
    renewed                 enum('f','t')
    decline_reason_id       unsigned int(F decline_reason.id)

+----+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
| id | customer_id | product_id | beg_date   | end_date   | price | renewed | decline_reason_id |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
|  1 |           1 |          2 | 2015-01-10 | 2016-01-10 | 25.00 |    NULL |              NULL |
|  2 |           1 |          3 | 2015-02-10 | 2018-02-10 | 75.00 |    NULL |              NULL |
|  3 |           1 |          4 | 2016-01-10 | 2017-01-10 | 28.00 |    NULL |              NULL |
| .. | ........... | .......... | .......... | .......... | ..... | ....... | ................. |    +----+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+-------------------+
```

A table of decline reasons.

```
decline_reason
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50)

+----+----------------+
| id | description    |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Too expensive  |
|  2 | Didn't like it |
| .. | .............. |
+----+----------------+
```

A table of all the plans to which `customer`'s could have subscribed. You'll note there are two Plan 1 products - the first Plan 1 was offered from January 1, 2013 to January 1, 2014 and was $20.00. The next Plan 1 became effective January 1, 2014 but cost $25.00. Many products/services go up in price over time, this is one way to "version" your products.

```
product
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(255)
    term            unsigned int
    price           double
    beg_date        date
    end_date        date

+----+-------------+------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | description | term | price  | beg_date   | end_date   |
+----+-------------+------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Plan 1      |    1 | 20.00  | 2013-01-01 | 2014-01-01 |
|  2 | Plan 1      |    1 | 25.00  | 2014-01-01 | 2015-02-12 |
|  3 | Plan 2      |    3 | 100.00 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-09-15 |
|  4 | Plan 3      |    1 | 35.00  | 2015-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |
| .. | ........... | .... | ...... | .......... | .......... |
+----+-------------+------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. However this doesn't handle changing to a different plan at renewal or adding an add-on at renewal. Also, why keep products/add-ons separate when the relation is exactly the same. I could understand your point if you had a `customer_product_addons` table instead of `customer_addons`.

Comment: @Marcus - I've edited my example data to show a customer subscribing to Plan 3 at renewal time from Plan 1 (see the `customer_product` table). As for why keep products/addons separate - I've had to make a bunch of assumptions on how your data is related (ie the business rules). This was intended only to illustrate where I'd begin given the limited information available to me.

Comment: Guys, I know this is old but I could not find anything close to this kind of architectural discussion on database design related to SaaS products. Marcus and @BennyHill – are there any resources you could recommend reading on the subject (apart from this thread, apparently - which is gold)?

Comment: @pop - almost everything I know are things I've picked up over the last 20 years in the industry from clients, partners and conferences. Here's one suggestion I have for you though: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin

Comment: Thanks @BennyHill - I'll look into it.